# contact form doesnt send from mobile

Tags: html, forms, mobile

The contact form on my website doesn't work on phones and it supposed to open a program like gmail or mail app to send a message to me or just send right away.

I don't really know how to search for this problem but already tried to find a solution on multiple forums and google but couldn't find any :(

hope you guys know how to help me out

[my own website](http://jmb-designs.nl/)

(still learning html and css so please try keep it simple if you know a solution)

```
<section id="contact" class="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center animateup">
                    <h2>Contact</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gap-50"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 animateup">
                    <form role="form" action="mailto:jacootje14@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                                <textarea placeholder="Message" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Comment:**
Alright so now the mail works on mobile but now i have a new issue with the form because i cant type a message in the form before it opens outlook mobile app. (this issue also occurs on pc)

thanks in Advance!

Comment: *How* does it not work? What happens? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Please add your current code to the question so we know what you have tried to make this work.

Comment: i expect that my contact form would send even on phone but it does nothing on phones. i think it has something to do with the fact that it is a template and has a few bootstrap codes as well

Comment: Thats not how you submit forms. You need a server or some 3rd party solutions. If you want to open an email client to write a message you need to add that "mailto:jacootje14@gmail.com" to a link

Comment: action="mailto:jacootje14@gmail.com" i did right ?

Comment: No, add it to `a` tags `href`, so `href="mailto:jacootje14@gmail.com"`

Comment: alright so now the mail works on mobile but now i have a new issue with the form because i cant type a message in the form before it opens outlook mobile app. (this issue also occurs on pc) @zmuci